# What are possible reasons for "Potentially dangerous Request.RawUrl"?

Tags: asp.net, exception, webforms, rawurl

In an asp.net web forms application we get an error message with "A potentially dangerous Request.RawUrl" sometimes, but I cannot find the source of it.

What are the possible reasons for this exception?

---

Some details from our case:

```
Event message: A validation error has occurred

Exception type: System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException

Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.RawUrl value was 
detected from the client (="..._Combin%20%20%20%20%20%2...").

Request URL: https://somesite/somepage.aspx
?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_sm1_HiddenField
&_TSM_Combin%20</div>%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20<div%20id=

Stack trace:    at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String s, String valueName, String collectionName)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_RawUrl()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.somepage_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I recognise the part with TSM_HiddenField in the html of the generated page:

```
<script src="/somepage.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_sm1_HiddenField&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=
%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d3.5.11119.20050%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c
+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3ada-DK%3a8e147239-dd05-47b0-8fb3-f743a139f982
%3ae2e86ef9%3a1df13a87%3a8ccd9c1b%3ac4c00916%3a9ea3f0e2%3a9e8e87e9
%3a4c9865be%3aba594826%3ac76f1358" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

... so it seems to be related to AjaxControlToolkit in this case, but how can this exception happen?

(It happens when a user is logged in, so I doubt there is some crawler or hack attempt involved...)

Comment: What is making the request be a get instead of a post?  That would be where I'd see the error popping up.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have HTML markups in the submitted form fields, could be this one:

```
&_TSM_Combin%20</div>%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20<div%20id=
```

The `<div>`'s the culprit.

Comment: I think that would have given a "potentially dangerous Request.Form" exception. Here it is Request.RawUrl instead of Request.Form.

Comment: @Ole, it's in the URL as a querystring `?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_sm1_HiddenField
&_TSM_Combin%20</div>%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20<div%20id=
`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. It is in the url for some script generated by asp.net. I think form fields with html would generate a "potentially dangerous Request Form" exception instead of Request.RawUrl...

Comment: @Ole: That should be the case, I guess.

Comment: I will downvote this one, since it seems quite misleading and not addressing the question...

Comment: Agreed, this doesn't actually help answer the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* it has to do with ASP.NET request validation: http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/request-validation/

It throws the exception if e. g. HTML tags are sent with the request.